# Groupby leaving out record

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display the goalscorers on my site and noticed an issue with my query. The match in question has 3 goalscorers but one player scored twice. The following query will return two players with the second having num_goals = 2

```
SELECT p.lastname, pg.time,  COUNT(pg.id) as num_goals,
FROM `exp_tm_player_goals` pg
JOIN exp_tm_players p ON ( p.id = pg.player )
WHERE `match` ='101565'
AND `team` ='202'
Group By p.id
```

The above gives the following result

```
lastname    time     numgoals   
Hunter      50       1
Lynn        75       2
```

After looking at it again this is expected behaviour and the following would return the correct number.

```
SELECT p.lastname, pg.time, 
FROM `exp_tm_player_goals` pg
JOIN exp_tm_players p ON ( p.id = pg.player )
WHERE `match` ='101565'
AND `team` ='202'
```

Results in

```
lastname    time   
Hunter      50      
Lynn        75       
Lynn        90
```

But what I was hoping to do was group players as well as time so it would be possible to have firstname, lastname, times,

```
lastname    time   
Hunter      50      
Lynn        75,90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a group_concat over the field times. So you first query was almost right:

```
SELECT p.lastname, GROUP_CONCAT(pg.time SEPARATOR ','), COUNT(pg.id) as num_goals
FROM `exp_tm_player_goals` pg
JOIN exp_tm_players p ON ( p.id = pg.player )
WHERE `match` ='101565'
AND `team` ='202'
Group By p.id
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat for all possibilities

Comment: The default separator is comma, so you could even simplify to GROUP_CONCAT(pg.time)